# Beamer: text that looks like enumerate bullet

Tags: beamer, enumerate

The `Rochester` theme styles `enumerate` bullets nicely using a dark square with white text. For example, the MWE

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[height=50pt]{Rochester}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Example}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Do this.
            \item Do that.
            \item Go to step 1.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

gives us

[image: Beamer rochester enumerate]

In step **3**, it would be nice to style the "1" so it looks just like the bullet.

I know I could do this with `colorbox` and `textcolor`, but this does not pull the styling from the theme, so if I change to a different theme later it will no longer match. For example, `Frankfurt` has the 3D-shaded sphere effect.

Does Beamer provide a way to do this, i.e. a hypothetical command like `\enumbulletstyle{1}`?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). You are more likely to get an answer if you provide compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added the MWE.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the definition of the [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer) template for an enumerated item under `Rochester` (taken from [`beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty):

```
\defbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{square}
{
  \hbox{%
    \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
    \vrule width2.25ex height1.85ex depth.4ex%
    \hskip-2.25ex%
    \hbox to2.25ex{%
      \hfil%
      \color{fg}\insertenumlabel%
      \hfil}%
  }%
}
[action]
{\setbeamerfont{item projected}{size=\scriptsize}}
```

Extracting only the pertinent information, you can create a macro for inserting a similarly-formatted item in your list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Rochester}

% Taken partially from the beamer template for enumerate item in
%   http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty
% Rochester uses a square enumerated item template
\newcommand{\enumlabelref}[1]{%
  \hbox{%
    \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
    \vrule width2.25ex height1.85ex depth.4ex%
    \hskip-2.25ex%
    \hbox to2.25ex{%
      \hfil%
      \color{fg}#1%
      \hfil}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Do this. \label{enum:first-item}
    \item Do that.
    \item Go to step \enumlabelref{1}.
    \item Go to step \hyperref[enum:first-item]{\enumlabelref{\ref*{enum:first-item}}}.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The two options provided above show how you can use references rather than hard-coded numbers.

---

For a more generic way of using whatever template is chosen by the theme, use this version of `\enmlabelref`:

```
\newcommand{\enumlabelref}[1]{{%
  \expandafter\patchcmd\csname beamer@@tmpl@enumerate item\endcsname% <cmd>
    {\insertenumlabel}% <search>
    {#1}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
  \usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}%
}}
```

Comment: This is great, but it's still specific to the `Rochester` template, correct? For example, `Frankfurt` has the 3D-shaded spheres. Is there a way to define  a command that would look correct for any theme? (Apologies, I could have stated this goal more clearly in the question.)

Comment: @japreiss: See the update at the end of my answer.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: Warning: Unreachable code in bullet 4. ;)